# Name for "multiple output" CDF for multivariate distributions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

There are two ways to think of the CDF. One is the integral of the pdf from $-\infty$ to $x$, and another is to think of it as the inverse of the monotonic one-to-one function that maps the unit interval to the pdf.

In 1-D, these two interpretations give the same answers, but in higher-dimensions they have different interpretations. The CDF is defined as single-output function that integrates the PDF over the multiple input variables. What would we call the other interpretation? That is, the function that maps the unit cube to a location in the density and its inverse?

As an example, one way to generate multivariate Gaussian random variables is to sample from the unit cube, compute the Gaussian inverse CDF on each of the dimensions, and compute $x = \mu + Lz$. Given a sample from this multivariate Gaussian, we can do the inverse transformation to get a point on the unit cube. What are these operations called?

Comment: by 'maps the unit interval to the pdf' surely you mean 'maps the unit interval to the distribution quantiles'?

Comment: or 'the support of the PDF'? In any event, maybe 'quantile function' is the name you're looking for...

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Usually, the quantile is defined as the inverse of the CDF. If quantile is the word I'm looking for, then is there a name for the inverse quantile function for multivariate distributions?

Comment: Not sure if I'm exactly getting what you're asking, but are you familiar with copulas? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)

Comment: Sorry, your last comment didn't show up for some reason till after I entered. It's not the inverse quantile function, it's the quantile function (it's the inverse CDF in one dimension). I haven't seen it talked about much in multiple dimensions (and it's certainly not the inverse of the multivariate CDF) but there is a one-to-one map between the unit cube and multivariable quantiles. If I were to call it something, I'd call it a 'quantile function'. (It's possible this is well known and I'm just ignorant of it.)

Comment: Actually I'm going to back off on my claim that there's clear and useful notion of 'multivariable quantiles'. Sure you can take the quantiles of the individual marginal distributions as a pair, but this would seem to not carry any joint information.